# Eloquent event not firing from CLI (outside Laravel)

Tags: php, eloquent

I have the following event handler in my model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    //...

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($user) {
            // die('inside');
            if (empty($user->username)) {

                $base = strtolower($user->first_name . '.' . $user->last_name);

                do {
                    $username = $base . @$suffix;
                    $duplicate = User::where('username', '=', $username)->first();
                } while($duplicate and $suffix = rand(1000, 9999));

                // return the original/ generated username
                $user->username = $username;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Basically when username is not set, the model will automatically generate a unique username from the first/last name. This works fine in the browser. But not in the CLI when I'm running my tests - username is not set, so it attempts to insert without username which my mysql table doesn't accept.

Below is how I'm setting up Eloquent console:

```
$capsule = new \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager;
$capsule->addConnection([
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'database' => 'sso_dev',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'vagrant1',
        ]);
$capsule->setEventDispatcher( new \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher( new \Illuminate\Container\Container ));
$capsule->bootEloquent();
$capsule->setAsGlobal();
```

Both the web environment and testing use this same code. If I comment the line `setEventDispatcher` then the browser environment throws an error as the event handler doesn't fire. So I know the event dispatcher is doing it's job there. Just not the testing CLI environment. Any reason why this might be?

Btw I'm using Eloquent 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a call to the setEventDispatcher again when it boots.

```
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();

    static::setEventDispatcher(new \Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher());
    static::saving(function ($model){
        // now you can reference your model
    }
}
```